# How to open and get input from a popup before running test?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium2, browser-automation, testng

I want to open a popup before running my tests and after completing my test run. I want to give few inputs from the popup on basis of that my test will run.

Suppose I have multiple links on which my project is present to test. I want to select the link from popup and then my test cases should run on that selected link.

I have made an html file which have all fields necessary for me. I am trying to open that file in a popup before selenium start running my tests.

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this? I am using Selenium webdriver with Testng.

Comment: What programming language? What xUnit framework?

Comment: I am using java and Testng framework.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know a framework named "Testing" and when I google for it, I can not find it. Do you have a link for me?

Comment: He says he is using TestNG not testing, you can find the website here: http://testng.org/

Comment: hey @Niels any kind of suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, a mistake on my part. I read too fast. I answered your question and hope it helps.

Comment: Are you referring to a pop up like this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html ?

Answer (score 1):

TestNG provide a lot of annotations for thinks like that: `@BeforeTest`, `@BeforeSuite`, `BeforeGroups` and more: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

It may be look like that:

```
@BeforeTest
public void setup() {
    // open your popup and click on the link
}

@Test
public void test() {
    // test case
}

@AfterTest
public void tearDown() {
    // close popup
}
```

TestNG also provide Listeners: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners. With Listeners you can say what before or after a test happens. Also what happens when a test finish, failed, skipped or succeed. Maybe this provide a better way for you.

Comment: I am facing problem in opening popup. That popup may contain a dropdown. so need to get that selected value from dropdown and then proceed.

Comment: Selenium 2 / WebDriver has a `Select` class for dropdowns: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html